# How to sort a pandas dataframe by the standard deviations of its columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following example :

```py
from statistics import stdev
d = pd.DataFrame({"a": [45, 55], "b": [5, 95], "c": [30, 70]})
stds = [stdev(d[c]) for c in d.columns]
```

With output:

```py
In [87]: d
Out[87]:
    a   b   c
0  45   5  30
1  55  95  70

In [91]: stds
Out[91]: [7.0710678118654755, 63.63961030678928, 28.284271247461902]
```

I would like to be able to sort the columns of the dataframe by their
standard deviations, resulting in the following

```
    b   c   a
0   5  30  45
1  95  70  55
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are looking for:

```
 d.iloc[:,(-d.std()).argsort()]
Out[8]: 
    b   c   a
0   5  30  45
1  95  70  55
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the column order like this:

```
column_order = d.std().sort_values(ascending=False).index
# >>> column_order
# Index(['b', 'c', 'a'], dtype='object')
```

And then sort the columns like this:

```
d[column_order]                                                                                                                                                                                           

    b   c   a
0   5  30  45
1  95  70  55
```